# Inspect cordova app local storage?

Tags: cordova

I have local storage working fine on all browsers on my computer, but when I convert it into a cordova android app, it's not working and I can't find how to inspect the local storage on the android device.

Just for general inspecting it would be good to see what is inside the local storage for that device.

I have tried http://debug.phonegap.com/ but that wasn't working.

So is there a way to inspect the code when on the device, I have used the ADT for inspecting web pages on the device but I don't think that works when the code is native?

Found a solution here [Weinre not working, trying to debug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444851/weinre-not-working-trying-to-debug) use "weinre" its amazing.

Comment: can you show some code?

Comment: I don't see what I would need to show, I am just trying to figure out how to inspect the console and local storage on the android device.

Comment: Why not logging it in logcat using `console.log`? I'm sure you have already did this though.

Comment: I saw someone said they did that, but it required searching etc I wasnt sure if it included local storage, I figured it was just a console. I think I may try it out to see if it will meet what I need. Well I just checked logcat out in eclipse and its quite foreign, I cant find anything about local storage inside it.

Comment: Does this work with cordova? https://build.phonegap.com/docs/advanced-debugging and can I use this without paying? Looks like I would have to upload the app here first using my one free app, then after debugging rebuild then package as cordova?

Comment: See this.. this solved my problem "weinre" is the answer its awesome in debugging, once connected to your device remotely you can inspect it like chrome dev tools or firebug http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444851/weinre-not-working-trying-to-debug

Answer (score -1):

if you are using a device or emulator with Android version > 4.4 you can access it with Chrome's inspector [here](http://chrome://inspect/#devices). So the steps you have to follow are:

1- launch you app into your device

2- open Chrome's inspector

3-Select you device/app

4- then you can inspect like you used to do in the browser. Local storage is in Application tab

Comment: Application tab is empty with both device and emulator.