# How to read variables in internal storage stored by Plugins in Cordova/Android?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, local-storage, rate

Is there a way of knowing what variables are stored in my App's internal storage. I am using Cordova for an Android App and I want to know what kind of variables [AppRate](http://E:%5CPhoneGap%5CQuran-for-All%3Ecordova%20plugins%20add%20https://github.com/pushandplay/cor%20dova-plugin-apprate.git) plugin is storing on my device and what are their values. I obviously know what my App is storing but I don't know about the plugins.

Comment: possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20435784/inspect-cordova-app-local-storage

Comment: Possible, but no acceptable answer there either.